# Azure SQL: Modify table data via UI instead of writing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Is there a way I can modify the table data in an Azure SQL database via some sort of UI (like Excel) instead of having to write SQL queries? Preferably I can modify it online in the Azure Portal instead of having to install some third-party software.

Often times, I just want to edit a specific cell in the table and I feel it would be way easier if I could just double click on that specific cell to edit it instead of having to write a SQL query.

Right now, I am only able to edit data by writing queries, but I can't actually edit the data in the table by double-clicking (the red box highlighted is uneditable).

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use SSMS or Azure Data Studio? Both can accomplish your requested functionality.

Comment: In SSMS. right click table, edit top 200 rows. It's unforunately not trivial to build an app for editing databases. Or you could try something like this https://sqledit.com/de/index.html

Comment: Try a google search on 'SQL Clients' and learn how to connect your preferred sql client with your db on Azure.

Comment: There is a reason why data is there in db tables - to ensure data 'integrity' by usage of various DB features - constraints, validation by business rules, referential integrity and so on! No one will anyways allow to edit data in production as you describe - it is not a excel sheet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit row on double click. On Azure portal follow these steps.
[image]

1. Go to Azure Sql database.
2. Left side menu blade select Query Editor
3. Connect to database. and under Tables folder click table three dot. popup small window open, select Edit Data(Preview).
   [image]
4. select Preview terms check box, then click ok.
   [image]
5. Double click on row , edit row enable.
   [image]
6. Change on FirstName from Punit to Sunit. Click top menu Save button and its save record to database.
   [image]
7. Final result.
   [image]